# Getting error when calling lambda function running locally on docker through browser

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, docker, cors

I have a docker image that I use to deploy my python code on AWS lambda. Then I enable function url and call it using javascript's fetch written inside an HTML file, which runs in a browser. I enabled CORS setting in the lambda configuration. It is functioning properly.
Here is my lambda function:

```
import json
import base64
def handler(event, context):
    print("EVENT")
    print(event)
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": "Cool!!!"
        }),
        "isBase64Encoded": False
    }
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Testing AWS Lambda</h1>
    <button type="submit" id="button">Click to send request</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
      // const endpointUrl = 'http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations';
      const endpointUrl = "https://<hidden-my-function-url>.lambda-url.ap-south-1.on.aws/"
      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
          var raw = JSON.stringify({ "from": "browser" });
      var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
      };
      fetch(endpointUrl, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
COPY app.py ./
CMD ["app.handler"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backtest-report-dashboard:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

Now when I run this image in docker locally, I get the following errors:
In browser console:
[image]
In docker container log:

```
2023-04-09 20:36:23 START RequestId: d5663539-81bd-45aa-b385-6e02cb12be46 Version: $LATEST
Traceback (most recent call last):e.UnmarshalError: Unable to unmarshal input: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2023-04-09 20:36:23 END RequestId: d5663539-81bd-45aa-b385-6e02cb12be46
2023-04-09 20:36:23 REPORT RequestId: d5663539-81bd-45aa-b385-6e02cb12be46      Duration: 15.74 ms      Billed Duration: 16 ms     Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 3008 MB
```

I don't know how to resolve this, I am doing this to quickly develop my application locally and then deploy it on lambda. Thank you.
One more thing, when I call my API using Postman, it is working properly.